# Vue-tags-input with default value from api

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using [vue-tags-input](https://github.com/JohMun/vue-tags-input)  and I want to set default value that I get from server api.
Now my value it doesn't look like tags, it appears like a text, and if I have multiple value looks like "Test test2", like an input. I want to insert directly as a tag.
[image]   [image]

```
<div>
    <vue-tags-input
    v-model="tagName"
    :tagName="tagName"
    :allow-edit-tags="true"
    :autocomplete-items="items"
    :autocomplete-filter-duplicates="false"
    class="tags-input"
    @tags-changed="newTags => tags = newTags"
    />
</div>

props:['customer_names'],
data() {
    return {
    tagName: '',
    tags: [],
    };
},
mounted(){
    this.tagName = this.customer_names[0].name
    this.tagName += this.customer_names[1].name
},
```

Comment: Refer this http://www.vue-tags-input.com/#/examples/styling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way.

In my div I replace `:tagName="tagName"` with `:tags="tags"` and:

```
mounted(){
    var result = this.data_from_api.map(item => ({ "text": item.name,"tiClasses":["ti-valid"] }));
    this.tags = result;
},
```